# is there documents to tell me best about iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have just bought a mac pc. It has maverics os with xcode 5.0.2.

I want to develop iphone application but i don't have an iphone device.

So i want to ask you if there is something over the internet that tells me that best practice for screens and buttons and table views on iphone.

what i mean is, i want to develop apps similar to those who user used to use. for instance, user by default have experience with navigation bar and they expect to see it.

#### i hope you got me, if not pelase tell me

#### edit

i mean that. if you wnat to make application to show players and you will give the chance to the user to add his player. they you make the `+` sign at the top right of the navigation bar. it is not good to add a button to the bottom of the screen.

Comment: No we don't get you. You brought a mac and you want to start developing apps. That's all we got. If you want to do this go on google and google "Hello world tutorials in objective-c" (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=hello+world+tutorials+in+objective-c&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=vbfNUpOPO-6A7QbOqoCwAw) voting to close as off-topic as it shows minimal understanding.

Comment: @Popeye i mean that. if you wnat to make application to show players and you will give the chance to the user to add his player. they you make the `+` sign at the top right of the navigation bar. it is not good to add a button to the bottom of the screen. got me now?

Comment: How does your question ask any of what you have just said? Now I am going to say what have you tried? What code do you have? What have you looked at? This is basic stuff that you will get shown how to do this in many tutorials. I will also now advice you to read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380 oh and by the way my vote to close remains for the same reason.

Comment: @Popeye it seems you are nervious buddy. thanks for your comments and thanks for your `-1` to my question. please you did what you want to do. lets see other peoples answers. best regards

Comment: There are multiple users that think the exact same since this one needs a one more vote to close and you have 4 -1 already. Your question just doesn't make sense at all and demonstrates zero understanding of anything you are trying to do. How do I seem nervious? I know exactly what I am talking about, maybe take a look at my profile and you will see I know.

Comment: @Popeye i am not interesting on your profile.

Comment: You are a very naive person. I am being polite and providing you with some advice, that you are best taking because some people will be brutal on this site. Your question remains the same and doesn't ask a question and shows a minimal understanding have you even taken a glance at either link I provided? You will be best of reading the link about how to ask a question. And it is "`I'm not interested in your profile"`.

Comment: @Popeye I am not interested neither in your profile nor about your links.

Comment: then you will not make it very far on this site with that attitude. I will spell it out for you. Lack of research, lack of correct information, lack of code, and most importantly lack of a question will get you zero help. And being rude when some is trying to help you will also get you zero help, all I was trying to do was get you to provide the correct information for us to give you (Not me, I am giving my time to help you) the best possible answer, but I see all you want to do is be rude and aggressive. Again you will not get far with that attitude in life and on this site.

Comment: @Popeye you the one who start being aggessive. Also, I have got an answer, and the best answer, so please go and have a cup of coffee. I thank your time and your highly appreciated links. these links are the best things i have ever had. your notes are very beneifical to me. I can be more thankful to your advantage

Comment: @Popeye please how many votes i still need to make this question close ? also i would appreciate it if you give me links to descripee the policy of closing questions. i highly appreciate pages and links that deeply increase my understanding of closing questions.

Comment: One vote remains and if you stick to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380 you will not get any and read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10582/what-is-a-closed-or-on-hold-question for an understanding of closing questions and why they happen

Comment: @Popeye I am really sorry for being not good with you. I really hope you forgiev me. I am so sorry.

Comment: @Popeye please say something, i am sorry, i feel regrit cos i did that to you. from my heart i hope you forgiev me

Comment: I have given you the links that you asked for what else do you want?

Comment: i want to apology, and i hope you accept it. i want you to not be sad or mad of me. i realized that u was try to help me and i acted in not polite things. i hope u forgiev me

Comment: Honestly I don't care (Please don't take that in a bad way) it is only the person who asks the question that misses out not me. But if you think I was being rude I am sorry, but you will find as you go along on here people will be brutally honest with you and whilst it may come across as rude and aggressive they are just being honest don't take it to heart. And don't apologies for defending your opinion, I do this all the time even after I realize I was wrong, but I defend my answers and questions still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google would be a good start.

If you are just looking for best practices, that is all documented in the human interface guidelines.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/

Comment: is there a pdf contains all the information in that page please?

Comment: Yeah... the link to the pdf is on the same page - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/MobileHIG.pdf

Comment: please is this pdf for ios 7 ?

Answer (score -1):

You should do a search on "iOS Human Interface Guidelines" in the Xcode help system and read the extensive document set that comes up.

Comment: you are a polite person for answering my question, i appreciate your help and support. +1 to you. and accepted after 3 minutes

Comment: there is a people make `-1` to your answer, it is not me. i +1 this answer